# Pushing one element after every iteration in an array including the column length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array A where i am adding one element to B after every iteration, the problem is that my code works for 1D array. But since i am trying to pass a 2D array, the columns are turning into lines.
For example:

```
import numpy as np

test = np.array([
 [1, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2.3, 1.27, 1.22, 1, 1.14],
 [2, 3.01, 7.7, 9.6, 2.8, 5.4, 2.1, 7.47, 1, 4],
 [3, 8, 6.7, 7.1, 5.1, 4.7, 5.9, 4.7, 3.8, 3.05],
 [4, 6, 9.7, 3.3, 5.64, 8.41, 2.16, 3.38, 5.3, 8.5],
 [5, 4.25, 5.28, 1.8, 2.24, 2.79, 7.68, 9.56, 1.1, 1.47],
 [6, 5.18, 6.95, 2.63, 3.60, 4.83, 1.34, 1.86, 2.50, 3.64]])

A = test[0:6, 0:10]
print(A)
B = A[0:3, :]
for i in A[3:]:
    B = np.append(B, i)
    print(B.shape)
```

The output is:

```
(40,)
(50,)
(60,)
```

What i want to do is add 1 line (sample) while keeping the column length that is 10, the expected output would be:

```
 [1, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2.3, 1.27, 1.22, 1, 1.14],
 [2, 3.01, 7.7, 9.6, 2.8, 5.4, 2.1, 7.47, 1, 4],
 [3, 8, 6.7, 7.1, 5.1, 4.7, 5.9, 4.7, 3.8, 3.05],

 [1, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2.3, 1.27, 1.22, 1, 1.14],
 [2, 3.01, 7.7, 9.6, 2.8, 5.4, 2.1, 7.47, 1, 4],
 [3, 8, 6.7, 7.1, 5.1, 4.7, 5.9, 4.7, 3.8, 3.05],
 [4, 6, 9.7, 3.3, 5.64, 8.41, 2.16, 3.38, 5.3, 8.5],

 [1, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2.3, 1.27, 1.22, 1, 1.14],
 [2, 3.01, 7.7, 9.6, 2.8, 5.4, 2.1, 7.47, 1, 4],
 [3, 8, 6.7, 7.1, 5.1, 4.7, 5.9, 4.7, 3.8, 3.05],
 [4, 6, 9.7, 3.3, 5.64, 8.41, 2.16, 3.38, 5.3, 8.5],
 [5, 4.25, 5.28, 1.8, 2.24, 2.79, 7.68, 9.56, 1.1, 1.47],

[[1.   5.   4.   2.   2.   2.3  1.27 1.22 1.   1.14]
 [2.   3.01 7.7  9.6  2.8  5.4  2.1  7.47 1.   4.  ]
 [3.   8.   6.7  7.1  5.1  4.7  5.9  4.7  3.8  3.05]
 [4.   6.   9.7  3.3  5.64 8.41 2.16 3.38 5.3  8.5 ]
 [5.   4.25 5.28 1.8  2.24 2.79 7.68 9.56 1.1  1.47]
 [6.   5.18 6.95 2.63 3.6  4.83 1.34 1.86 2.5  3.64]]
```

But what the code actually outputs:

```
[1.   5.   4.   2.   2.   2.3  1.27 1.22 1.   1.14 2.   3.01 7.7  9.6
 2.8  5.4  2.1  7.47 1.   4.   3.   8.   6.7  7.1  5.1  4.7  5.9  4.7
 3.8  3.05 4.   6.   9.7  3.3  5.64 8.41 2.16 3.38 5.3  8.5  5.   4.25
 5.28 1.8  2.24 2.79 7.68 9.56 1.1  1.47 6.   5.18 6.95 2.63 3.6  4.83
 1.34 1.86 2.5  3.64]
```

Comment: Don't use `np.append` without actually reading its docs!  But why are you adding one column at a time to `b`?  Why not add all at once.  That's more efficient.  In `numpy` we try to work with the whole array, or big slices, at a time.  Iterating element by element, or column by column is less efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is:

```
B = np.append(B, i[None,:], 0)
```

which adds a dimension to `i` and appends along first axis `axis=0`. But appending to numpy array is costly and discouraged. I suggest using lists and converting to numpy array at the end.

output of your code:

```
(4, 10)
(5, 10)
(6, 10)
```

Comment: How would it look like by using lists?

Comment: @rckjns have a list of lists and append to a list to that list.